# Grouping then selecting the bottom row from one column

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a dataset where I need to group by one column and select the last row from that group in another column and taking the mean of the third column.
A sample is like this:

```
df <- data.frame(id=c("a","a","a","b","b","b","c","c","c"), 
                 name=c("a1","a2","a3","b1","b2","b3","c1","c2","c3"), 
                 v=c(1,2,3,3,1,4,3,1,2))
```

I have used dplyr to group and get the mean of v but not sure how to take the last value for the name column.

```
df %>%
   group_by(id) %>%
   summarise(mean(v))
```

The result shows as follows:

```
  id    `mean(v)`
  <fct>     <dbl>
1 a          2   
2 b          2.67
3 c          2
```

How can I add another column where it selects a3 for a and b3 for b and c3 for c?

Answer (score 2):

Selecting the last row can be seen as summarizing as well:

```
df %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  summarise(mean = mean(v), name = tail(name, 1))
# A tibble: 3 x 3
#   id     mean name 
#   <fct> <dbl> <fct>
# 1 a      2    a3   
# 2 b      2.67 b3   
# 3 c      2    c3
```

Answer (score 1):

All the following will work.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  summarise(mean = mean(v), name = last(name))
# # A tibble: 3 x 3
#   id     mean name 
#   <fct> <dbl> <fct>
# 1 a      2    a3   
# 2 b      2.67 b3   
# 3 c      2    c3   

df %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  summarise(mean = mean(v), name = nth(name, n()))
# # A tibble: 3 x 3
#   id     mean name 
#   <fct> <dbl> <fct>
# 1 a      2    a3   
# 2 b      2.67 b3   
# 3 c      2    c3 

df %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  summarise(mean = mean(v), name = name[n()])
# # A tibble: 3 x 3
#   id     mean name 
#   <fct> <dbl> <fct>
# 1 a      2    a3   
# 2 b      2.67 b3   
# 3 c      2    c3

df %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  summarise(mean = mean(v), name = name[length(name)])
# # A tibble: 3 x 3
#   id     mean name 
#   <fct> <dbl> <fct>
# 1 a      2    a3   
# 2 b      2.67 b3   
# 3 c      2    c3
```